# What is $E(X|XY)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Here we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ and we define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ on it. Define $Z := XY$. Let $E(X|XY) = E(X|\sigma(Z))$.

What is exactly $E(X|XY)$? If we assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent, can this be "simplified"?

Comment: I don't think it can be simplified even if they are independent.

Comment: Just for example, say $X,Y$ are (independently) in $\{0,1\}$ with equal chance.  If $XY=0$ then the possible pairs are $(X,Y)\in \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)\}$ so the probability that $X=0$ is $\frac 23$.  If $X$ is as before, but $Y$ (independently) is in $\{-1,1\}$ with equal chance, then knowing that $XY=0$ guarantees that $X=0$.